# How to write php code in script tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to write php code in script tag but something seems to be going wrong.
Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['column-count']))
$var = $_GET['column-count']; 
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <script>

            function send_column_count(){
            var col_count = document.getElementById('num-cols').value;
            alert(col_count);
            document.getElementById('column-count-id').value =   col_count ;
            var temp = document.getElementById('column-count- id').value;
            alert(temp);

            <?php
                for($i = 0;$i < $var ;$i = $i+1){
                $temp = "col".$i;
            echo " <input type='text' placeholder='column- name' id='" . $temp . "' />";
                }
            ?>
            alert('Reached here');

            return true;
        }

</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form align="center" method="GET" action="" >
            <h1>Snippt</h1>
            <select id="num-cols" onchange="send_column_count()">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <input type="hidden" name="column-count" id="column-count-id" value="7" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create Table" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the console shows the error message : Unexpected token <
I am not able to understand what's going wrong!

Comment: Why are you writing HTML inside script tag?

Comment: Move your `<?php ` block outside script tag

Comment: That's wrong... Mehul told ya, HTML code inside javascript.

Comment: Just add PHP code with single quotes like '<? echo "hello" ; ?>'

Comment: do u check $var before for? $var may be null inside for

Comment: @MehulMohan The thing is i need to insert input fields based on the value selected in combo-box and for that i am calling the javascript function to create them!!
If i do not include php code in javascript then how do i dynamically create input fields?

Comment: By using JS to create the fields instead of php.

Comment: Ok if i use javascript inside php then how will i assign id value dynamically as i am doing now? @Shilly

Comment: By counting how many children the select already has.  `document.getElementById('num-cols')` gives you the select itsself. `.childNodes.length` tells you how many options it currently has. Or rewrite the loop you have in js.

Answer (score 0):

Your original logic is totally flawed. You do not even need PHP to dynamically add the fields. But anyhow, I'm posting the correct version for your app which sort of works the same way you want it to work (with PHP):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$var = 0;
if(isset($_GET['column-count']))
$var = $_GET['column-count']; 
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script>

        function send_column_count(){
            var col_count = document.getElementById('num-cols').value;
            alert(col_count);
            document.location.href = location.href.split('?')[0]+"?column-count="+col_count; 
        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
                for($i = 0;$i < $var ;$i = $i+1){
                    $temp = "col" . $i;
                    echo " <input type='text' placeholder='column- name' id='" . $temp . "' />";
                }
            ?>
<form align="center" method="GET" action="" >
    <h1>Snippt</h1>     
    <select id="num-cols" onchange="send_column_count()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="column-count" id="column-count-id" value="7" />      
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create Table" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The JS way:

```
function send_col_count() {
var col_count = document.getElementById('num-cols').value;
var htmlConstructed = "";
for(i=0;i<col_count;i++) {
htmlConstructed += "<input type='text' id='col"+i+"' />";
}
document.getElementById('myCustomFields').innerHTML = htmlConstructed;
}

// and somewhere in body:

<div id="myCustomFields"></div>
```

Comment: I totally agree that using javascript will make it a lot easier but the only reason i am doing this is, i need to send the value that user inserts into the textfields, to a php file which further creates tables in mysql....
So if i do it the javascript way...it would become little complicated as i would be forced to use AJAX in that case to send the data to php file..

Comment: You can see the php/js version.